# Reordering arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Say, I have an array that looks like this:

```
var playlist = [
    {artist:"Herbie Hancock", title:"Thrust"},
    {artist:"Lalo Schifrin", title:"Shifting Gears"},
    {artist:"Faze-O", title:"Riding High"}
];
```

How can I move an element to another position?

I want to move for example, `{artist:"Lalo Schifrin", title:"Shifting Gears"}` to the end.

I tried using splice, like this:

```
var tmp = playlist.splice(2,1);
playlist.splice(2,0,tmp);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean -- does it throw an error, does it change nothing, does it change your array in a way you didn't intend?  It looks reasonable to me.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

The syntax of [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) is:

```
yourArray.splice(index, howmany, element1, /*.....,*/ elementX);
```

Where:

- *index* is the position in the array you want to start removing elements from
- *howmany* is how many elements you want to remove from *index*
- *element1, ..., elementX* are elements you want inserted from position *index*.

This means that `splice()` can be used to remove elements, add elements, or replace elements in an array, depending on the arguments you pass.

Note that it returns an array of the removed elements.

Something nice and generic would be:

```
Array.prototype.move = function (from, to) {
  this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
};
```

Then just use:

```
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5];
ar.move(0,3);
alert(ar) // 2,3,4,1,5
```

Diagram:

[image: Algorithm diagram]

Comment: This is a good answer, and the splice() within a splice() does the job well. It should be noted, however, that adding a move() method to the Array prototype is called "Monkey Patching" and is typically considered bad practice.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741877/is-monkey-patching-really-that-bad

Comment: Seems tricky using splice() there are some edge cases that are difficult to solve - that is in the case of reordering more than two items at a time.

Answer (score 31):

If you know the indexes you could easily swap the elements, with a simple function like this:

```
function swapElement(array, indexA, indexB) {
  var tmp = array[indexA];
  array[indexA] = array[indexB];
  array[indexB] = tmp;
}

swapElement(playlist, 1, 2);
// [{"artist":"Herbie Hancock","title":"Thrust"},
//  {"artist":"Faze-O","title":"Riding High"},
//  {"artist":"Lalo Schifrin","title":"Shifting Gears"}]
```

Array indexes are just properties of the array object, so you can swap its values.

Comment: Thanks, @CMS. If I swap mean's don't want to replace the order...For Example, If I select the 3rd object to 1 st position I want to swap 1 as a 2 and 2 as a 3 as 1

Answer (score 23):

With **ES6** you can do something like this:

```
const swapPositions = (array, a ,b) => {
  [array[a], array[b]] = [array[b], array[a]]
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
swapPositions(array,0,1);

/// => [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This swaps the two element's positions. Question is for reorder.

Answer (score 18):

Here is an immutable version for those who are interested:

```
function immutableMove(arr, from, to) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, current, idx, self) => {
    if (from === to) {
      prev.push(current);
    }
    if (idx === from) {
      return prev;
    }
    if (from < to) {
      prev.push(current);
    }
    if (idx === to) {
      prev.push(self[from]);
    }
    if (from > to) {
      prev.push(current);
    }
    return prev;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain to me the benefits of this function over the answer above ?

Comment: This solution does not modify the original element but returns a new array with the entry being moved.

Comment: @Xogno It is especially useful in frameworks like React that often requires immutable objects in order to detect changes

Comment: Thank you both for the explanations

Answer (score 11):

You could always use the sort method, if you don't know where the record is at present:

```
playlist.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.artist == "Lalo Schifrin" 
               ? 1    // Move it down the list
               : 0;   // Keep it the same
});
```

Comment: What about `return +(a.artist == "Lalo Schifrin")`

Comment: @Funko you could do that, if you prefer brevity over verbosity.

Answer (score 8):

Change 2 to 1 as the first parameter in the splice call when removing the element:

```
var tmp = playlist.splice(1, 1);
playlist.splice(2, 0, tmp[0]);
```

Comment: it should be playlist.splice(2,0,tmp[0]); Right?

Answer (score 8):

Immutable version, no side effects (doesn’t mutate original array):

```
const testArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function move(from, to, arr) {
    const newArr = [...arr];

    const item = newArr.splice(from, 1)[0];
    newArr.splice(to, 0, item);

    return newArr;
}

console.log(move(3, 1, testArr));

// [1, 4, 2, 3, 5]
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/mliq/pen/KKNyJZr

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: Please check out [Andy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440700/reordering-arrays/2440717#2440717) as his answer came first and this is solely an extension of his**

I know this is an old question, but I think it's worth it to include `Array.prototype.sort()`.

Here's an example from MDN [along with the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
var numbers = [4, 2, 5, 1, 3];
numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
console.log(numbers);

// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Luckily it doesn't only work with numbers:

> ## `arr.sort([compareFunction])`
>
> #### `compareFunction`
>
> Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.

I noticed that you're ordering them by first name:

```
let playlist = [
    {artist:"Herbie Hancock", title:"Thrust"},
    {artist:"Lalo Schifrin", title:"Shifting Gears"},
    {artist:"Faze-O", title:"Riding High"}
];

// sort by name
playlist.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.artist < b.artist) { return -1; }
  if(a.artist > b.artist) { return  1; }

  // else names must be equal
  return 0;
});
```

*note that if you wanted to order them by last name you would have to either have a key for both `first_name` & `last_name` or do some regex magic, which I can't do XD*

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This should be an edit to or comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440717/3757232).

Comment: @JaredSmith Oops! I didn't see his answer. I don't have enough points or whatever to edit his question, and I don't think all of this information should be added in a comment. So until someone edits his question I'll simply add that this is an extension to Andy E's answer(like I should of done).

Comment: I thinks it's fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
playlist = playlist.concat(playlist.splice(1, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever want to move one item from an arbitrary position to the end of the array, this should work:

```
function toEnd(list, position) {
    list.push(list.splice(position, 1));
    return list;
}
```

If you want to move multiple items from some arbitrary position to the end, you can do:

```
function toEnd(list, from, count) {
    list.push.apply(list, list.splice(from, count));
    return list;
}
```

If you want to move multiple items from some arbitrary position to some arbitrary position, try:

```
function move(list, from, count, to) {
    var args = [from > to ? to : to - count, 0];
    args.push.apply(args, list.splice(from, count));
    list.splice.apply(list, args);

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity of all answers is O(n^2) because had used twice `spice`. But O(n/2) is possible.

**Most Perfomance Solution:**

- Array with n elements,
- x is to, y is from
- should be n >x && n > y

time complexity should be  `|y - x|`. So its is number of elements that is between `from` and `to`.

- **bestcase**: O(1);  //ex: from:4 to:5
- **average** : O(n/2)
- **worthcase** : O(n) //ex: from:0 to:n

```js
function reOrder(from,to,arr) {
  if(from == to || from < 0 || to < 0  ) { return arr};
  var moveNumber = arr[from];
  if(from < to) {
    for(var i =from; i< to; i++){
      arr[i] = arr[i+1]
    }
  }

  else{
    for(var i = from; i > to; i--){
      arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    }
  }
  arr[to] = moveNumber;
  return arr;
}
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
console.log(reOrder(3,7,arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

As a simple mutable solution you can call splice twice in a row:

```
playlist.splice(playlist.length - 1, 1, ...playlist.splice(INDEX_TO_MOVE, 1))
```

On the other hand, a simple inmutable solution could use slice since this method returns a copy of a section from the original array without changing it:

```
const copy = [...playlist.slice(0, INDEX_TO_MOVE - 1), ...playlist.slice(INDEX_TO_MOVE), ...playlist.slice(INDEX_TO_MOVE - 1, INDEX_TO_MOVE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a rearranging complete array, I want something like I did below, but found most of the answers for moving only one element from position A to position B.

Hope my answer will help someone here

```
function reArrangeArray(firstIndex=0,arr){
    var a = [];
    var b = []
    for(let i = 0; i<= (arr.length-1); i++){
        if(i<firstIndex){
            a.push(arr[i])
        }else{
            b.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return b.concat(a)
}

const arrayToRearrange = [{name: 'A'},{name: 'B'},{name: 'C'},{name: 'D'},{name: 'E'}];

reArrangeArray(2,arrayToRearrange)

// Output
// [
//     { name: 'C' },
//     { name: 'D' },
//     { name: 'E' },
//     { name: 'A' },
//     { name: 'B' }
// ]
```

Answer (score -3):

**Reorder its work This Way**

```
 var tmpOrder = playlist[oldIndex];
    playlist.splice(oldIndex, 1);
    playlist.splice(newIndex, 0, tmpOrder);
```

I hope this will work

Comment: What does this add over the existing answers?