# All previous Mobile Views are visible in Worklight Android Application for Samsung devices with OS version higher the 4.1.x

Tags: android, mobile, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using dojo performTransition to switch between views and it is working fine all the devices except Samsung devices with Os version higher than 4.1.x

Transition is working but all the previous and next view are visible and I'm able to see all the screens that I navigate from on the screen by swapping the screen

Comment: Do you reproduce with one of the dojox/mobile testscase ? Also, which device (modele + Android version) exactly ?

Comment: I'm trying that now with dojox/mobile testcase. It is occuring in all Samsung mobile having Os version 4.1.x and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the following dojo defect:

Transition issue on some Android 4.1.x devices:
https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/17164

As well as this previous post that may help you based on Ken's and Idan's suggestions:

[IBM Worklight 6.0 - Dojo application doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006727/ibm-worklight-6-0-dojo-application-doesnt-work-on-samsung-galaxy-s3)

Comment: Issue here is transitions are working but all the navigated screens are still visible by swaping the screen. I applied above fix but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

manually hiding and showing screens using css display 'block' and 'none' after transition is finished worked for me.