# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - Is it possible to patch the used Dojo version?

Tags: android, eclipse, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

We are working with Worklight 5.0.6, using the included Dojo 1.8.3 build, to create a hybrid application for iOS, Android and mobile web.  Our iOS and mobile web testing have been working fine, but we are having an issue with our Android app, when testing on a Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.2).

If we have a dojox.mobile.button object on a ScrollableView, the onclick event for that button never gets fired.  After some research, we believe it is related to the issue at https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15878.  This appears to be fixed in Dojo 1.9, but we are not able to update the version of dojo with our app, since Worklight uses a minimized version of the libraries, not what is in our dojo folder in Eclipse.

Does anyone have any idea how to patch or upgrade the version of Dojo used by Worklight in Eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible (for you, the "end-user" developer) to swap the used Dojo version in Worklight.

What you could do, perhaps (didn't try), is use a [Monkey patch approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) as a "workaround". [See a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543998/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-include-dojo-patch-with-pre-built-dojo-layers) (not the same issue, though) where this approach was used to resolve an issue with Dojo in Worklight.

Comment: We were able to do the Monkey patch, temporarily, though we are probably going to upgrade to WL 6 in the near future, to allow us to use Dojo 1.9 directly.  We were actually able to replace the dojo version by custom building the full dojo suite, and modifying the build xml for dojo to include the appropriate files, but we have decided not to do this, since there are probably hidden issues that we won't know about.