# Override (save_model) in django admin for All models/apps in projects

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How could I implement override save method for all models in all Apps inside Admin panel?

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    
    pass
```

I can implement it in one or two models "inherit and adding it in register method", but I really need it to execute whenever admin clicks save in Admin panel and implement some code before save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my team we already overridden `ModelAdmin` class. Answer depends on your project.

In examples i use old python super() sintaxis, it helps to debug the code.

**Easy way** with class. Create somewhere in project

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin:

Class ModelAmin(ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some staff before
        super(ModelAdmin, self).save_model(*args, **kwargs)
        # do some staff after
```

Everywhere in project made find `from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin`
replace to `from module.with.myModelAdmin import ModelAdmin`.

All next ModelAdmins you should build with your `ModelAdmin`.

**Second way** with `ModelAdminMixin`. Code is fast the same. Somethere put mixin:

```
Class ModelAminMixin:
    def save_model(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some staff before
        super(ModelAdminMixin, self).save_model(*args, **kwargs)
        # do some staff after
```

Everywhere in project made find with regexp `class BlaBlaBla(bla, bla, ModelAdmin):` and replace to `class BlaBlaBla(bla, bla, ModelAdminMixin, ModelAdmin):`.

All next ModelAdmins you should build with inheritance from `ModelAdminMixin` and `ModelAdmin`.
This is a little bit more flexible: you can decide add or not this mixin.

**Next Way - MonkeyPatching**.

Somethere put your mixin from "second way".
Somethere in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin.
from module.with.myModelAdminMixin import ModelAdminMixin

ModelAdmin.__bases__ = (ModelAdminMixin,) + ModelAdmin.__bases__
```

After that you should not do something else. But it is a wrong way to code. [Is "monkey patching" really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741877/is-monkey-patching-really-that-bad)