# switch element position in jquery element collection

Tags: jquery, arrays

I solved using a json object in which i store the elements and their position. Now i can easily change the element values:

```
myJsonObject = {el:[pos: 1, el: element1], el2:[pos: 2, el: element2], etc}
```

---

i have an object which is a collection of dom elements, ie:

```
var els = $('#myDiv div');
```

What i need to do is switch the position of two element contained within this object. For example: the `element[2]` takes the place of `element[4]` and `element[4]` gets to `element[2]`.

Reading through the forum i find an array prototype function to do it on arrays:
[Reordering arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440700/reordering-arrays)

but i can't use it 'cause mine is not an array. Jquery has a function to change object into arrays called `makeArray`, but i must keep it as an object otherwise i cannot use all the jquery method i need later on to iterate over my object. 
Has anyone any idea?

Comment: what is the context? why do you need to reorder it?

Comment: hi, i'm doing a 'spacecollective.org' kind of layout. When i click on some elements the clicked one must move a few step further to keep the layout correct and make order..I'm not sure i've been clear but if you give a look to spacecollective you'll see what i mean (just click on the last two elements in a row)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery selections are just augmented arrays, so you can modify them directly using array notation.

```
var selection = $('#myDiv div');
var tmp = selection[2];
selection[2] = selection[4];
selection[4] = tmp;
```

I’m not convinced that what you’re doing is a good idea, but the above should work.

---

As an aside, in general if you have an array of nodes, or a NodeList, then  you can turn it into a JQuery selection by passing it as an argument to `$()`:

```
var nodes = documents.getElementsByTagName('p'); // Returns an ordinary NodeList
$(nodes).hide(); // You can run JQuery methods on the NodeList by passing it to $()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (crazy code, agree):

```
var els = $('#myDiv div');

var el2 = els.eq(1); // second element in collection
var el2clone = el2.clone( true );
var el4 = els.eq(3); // fourth element in collection

el2clone.after( el4 );
el4.after( el2 );
el2.remove();

els = $('#myDiv div');
```

Comment: I’m not sure why you’re cloning the elements. Taking a clone creates a new element, which isn’t what the OP wants.

Comment: @Daniel Cassidy Do you know another way to switch two elements in DOM?

Comment: My understanding is that he wants to switch their position in the **selection**, but the question is ambiguous so I may have got that wrong. Besides, it is possible to switch two elements in the DOM without cloning them, although it’s fiddly and JQuery doesn’t offer anything to help.