# Javascript arrays // reordering an array starting at a specified index while keeping the original order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Having the following array :

```
var arr = [a,b,c,d,e];
```

I'm struggling to get a clean function that sorts the array based on a specified index, keeping at the same time the original order

For example, sorting the array from index 3 (so here, from "d"), would give the following :

```
[d,e,a,b,c]
```

From index 2 :

```
[c,d,e,a,b]
```

etc...

It might be obvious for some but I can't make it in my mind

Help appreciated, thx in advance

*** Edit ***

Is a duplicate. Here is a good one.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861200/102133

Comment: I don't think the word "sort" is appropriate here, as "sorting" means "reordering".  Rotate maybe?

Comment: Yep "reordering" sounds better

Comment: start from the index a go the end after that restart from 0 index and go to the first starting index. Try it yourself... You can use two loops for that...

Comment: but you got the idea right ?

Comment: @esner_togo well I tried a lot that's why I'm asking here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440700/reordering-arrays

Comment: @esner_togo I think that's enough code to get the idea

Comment: @Boann thanks a lot, going to look into it

Comment: Curious.. how is it possible that this question is still receiving answers when it is closed as a duplicate?

Comment: @Boann did i do something wrong ?

Comment: @Ben No. But the question has been marked as a duplicate. As far as I know, that makes it impossible for anyone to post an answer on it, yet they are.

Comment: @Boann SO's buggy then ?

Comment: Found explanation: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible

Comment: @Boann Hope I'm not duplicating again on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27890656/javascript-arrays-comparing-two-similars-arrays-and-getting-object-that-needs but that'd be in the end what I really look for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

function reorder(data, index) {
  return data.slice(index).concat(data.slice(0, index))
};

console.log(reorder(arr, 3));
console.log(reorder(arr, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

This function will do your work

```
var reorder = function(arr,index){
    var start = arr.slice(index); // This will return me elements from a given index
    var end = arr.slice(0,index); // This will return me elements before a given index
    return start.concat(end); // Concat 2nd array to first and return the result.
 }
```