# interchange array using shift method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, backbone.js

I am trying to interchange array and print it using shift method but not sure whether I can use it or not.

[Code Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/h0903tgg/1/) below.

```js
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];

//trying to achieve like anotherPoints array
//var anotherPoints = [1, 5, 100, 40, 25, 10];

for (index = 0; index < points.length; index++) {
  points.shift();
  console.log(points);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some logic to get the desired result:

```js
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10],
    temp1 = [], temp2 = [], anotherArray;
points.forEach(function(val){
    if(val < 10 ) {
        temp1.push(val)
    } else {
        temp2.push(val);   
    }
});
anotherArray = temp1.sort().concat(temp2.sort(function(a,b){return b- a}));
alert(anotherArray);
```

It's not possible via `shift` or `splice`. Unless manually creating the array.

Answer (score 0):

The shift() method doesn't shift or interchange the elements of an Array. It is similar to pop(), but it pops out the first element from the Array.

For example,

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
console.log(points.shift());  // 40
console.log(points); // [100, 1, 5, 25, 10]
```

As to your requirement of rearranging the elements of an Array, you will have to use Array.splice() method. Check out this question [Reordering arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440700/reordering-arrays).