# how to apply a position field to a collection within Meteor mongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

My Use case

I have a playlist for an online music player. Currently they sorted by natural order when they are displayed.

I would like to put in a field for a track position within a playlist.

What would be the best way to implement this for a collection in meteor mongo db.

Here is my current schema for my Songs collection.

```
    //Schema for Songs
    Schema.Songs = new SimpleSchema({
      trackId: {
        type: String,
        label: "Track ID",
        optional: false
      },
      title: {
        type: String,
        label: "Name",
        optional: false
      },
      duration:{
        type: Number,
        label: "Duration",
        optional: false
      },
      festivalId: {
        type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id,
        optional: false
      }
    });
```

I would like to be able to reorder the songs, for example a song at position 3. I would like to move it to position 1 and then all other songs position field would update appropriately .

What would be a good starting point for this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that comes to mind is to have a collection called `playlist` which as a field called `songs`. The `songs` field would be an array of strings. These would be ID's of `Songs`

```
Schema.Playlist = new SimpleSchema({
  'songs.$': {
    type: String,
  }
})
```

You can then create a helper to list all the `song`. Let's call it `showPlaylist`. It resolves the ID's inside the `songs` field to their perspective documents. I'd make the array returned by `showPlaylist` reactive. That would save you some work.

```
{{ #each showPlaylist }}
  <audio id="{{ _id }}" class="song" src="{{ src }}"></audio>
{{ /each }}
```

Now you'll have to write something for the user to reorder the list and call this:

```
function updatePlaylistOrder (oldPos, newPos, id) {
  var newList = moveElement(Playlists.findOne(id), oldPos, newPos)
  Playlists.update(playlistId, {$set: {songs: newList}})
  return newList
}
```

[Credit for the `moveElement` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440723/4386702) to [/u/Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt)