# Z-Index control objects in FabricJS using jQuery UI sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, fabricjs

Hi I want to have Layers sort control like on photoshop using FabricJS

[image]

I have this solution but it's not working well when you have more than 3 objects on canvas:

```
$("#containerLayers").sortable({
  change: function(event, ui){
    $( "#containerLayers li" ).each(function(index,list){
        if(objectArray[$(list).attr('id')]){
            canvas.moveTo(objectArray[$(list).attr('id')],index);
        }
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
});
```

Here is other parts of code:
https://jsfiddle.net/peLcju2h/16/

does anyone have a better solution than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution for Layer ordering using FabricJS is this one:

```
$("#containerLayers").sortable({
    update: function(event, ui){

        var items = $(this).children();

        items.each(function(i,item){
            canvas.sendToBack(objectArray[item.id]);
        });
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

Instead of using `canvas.moveTo()` just use `canvas.sendToBack()` and it will work perfect

Here is link and you can see that ordering is working good
https://jsfiddle.net/peLcju2h/24/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have some important refactorings to make in your code, mainly because of the fact that a lot of its snipets are duplicated.

I did it already, and the final working code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/peLcju2h/18/

---

Let's see some considerations:

- All the Canvas object creations had the same code, so wrap it into a function;
- You were adding objs to your array through `push()` function, which is not wrong, but it messed up with your UI sortable handling. That's because every time you change `li`'s position, only the canvas and HTML are updated, but not the array itself.

  You could use a [reordering function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440700/reordering-arrays) for this, but it wouldn't fit the goal here once element positions don't have a predefined order or changing logic.

  Instead, I decided to go with an auxiliary array, which is gonna be populated every time the items are sorted.
- Push the items via `[]` operator into the array, using the object `id` as the key;
- In the end, notice that I put [a **promise**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941358/1269558) to guarantee the new `objectArray` will be rendered only after the canvas work has been done.

> ***Note:*** **JSFiddle** only works with HTTPS external links, so make sure you
>   import them correctly in future attempts, even if you're doing this
>   via CSS `@import`.

Comment: It has same problem when you have more than 3 elements.

Comment: @EdinPuzic you have to be more specific when describing a "problem". There's a whole implementation that makes a lot of things and, for me, is working fine. Please, be aware of this for future questions, because people take (sometimes) a lot of time trying to help.